# Android wall post update not working if Facebook app is installed

Tags: android-emulator

I have developed an application which posts wall post update on the Facebook. But the problem is if the Facebook app is already installed on the device, It's not working. But I tried in emulator without the Facebook app installed in it and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

1 for the activitycode parameter in the authorize method. This will force user to login disabling SSO. I solved the same issue by doing the same....